# open stack ubuntu 22.04 cloud image does not boot

Tags: boot, 22.04, openstack, cloud

I import a cloud image ( jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img ) to my openstack.
Than i start a instance.
Than i go to the console window of the instance and there was a message:

> Booting from hard disk
> boot failed: no bootable disk
>
> no bootable device.

is this normal?
how can i make it boot ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename it with following command
   mv jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2
2. Run the following command to upload it into glance
   glance image-create --name "ubuntu22-cloud-img" --file jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2 --disk-format qcow2 --min-ram 1024 --min-disk 20 --container-format bare  --visibility public --progress
3. Create virtual machine from newly created image "ubuntu22-cloud-img"